# complexity of graph 2.5-coloring

Tags: graph-algorithms, parameterized-complexity

My question is inspired by [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/49288/12859). ​ I define *2.5-coloring* to be the [parameterized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity) problem

Instance: an integer j and an n-vertex non-empty [simple graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html) G

Parameter: integer k

Output: if there is a 3-[coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) of G in which at least one of

the colors is used at most ​ min($\hspace{.03 in}$j,k) ​ times then YES else NO

.
Since j is part of the input and the only involvement of k is via  ​ min($\hspace{.03 in}$j,k) , ​ increasing k

cannot make 2.5-coloring easier. ​ ​ ​ ​ Even for k=0, that problem [is logspace-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL_(complexity)#Complete_problems).

For k in n<sup>[Ω](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Knuth_definition)(1)</sup>, that problem is NP-hard by enlarging 3-coloring instances.

By applying [Reingold's result](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/148550/sl.pdf) to the [bipartite double cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_double_cover) of the subgraph [induced by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Subgraphs) the

non-guessed vertices, 2.5-coloring is in ​ ​ [GC](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:G#gc) ( max(k$\cdot \hspace{-0.02 in}\lceil \log_2(n)\hspace{-0.02 in}\rceil \hspace{-0.03 in}$,n) , [DSPACE](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:D#dspace)(O(log(n))) ) ,

since the verifier [has two-way access](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0097539793258295#page=4) to the alleged proof.

> Is anything else known about the complexity of 2.5-coloring?

In particular, **I'd accept any non-trivial consequence of any answer to any of the following,


since I do not expect anyone to manage to outright answer any of them:**

Is 2.5-coloring in ​ co[NTIME](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#ntime)$\left(\hspace{-0.02 in}n^{o(k)}\hspace{-0.04 in}\right)\hspace{-0.07 in}\big/\hspace{-0.04 in}$[$n^{o(k)}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#ppoly) ? ​ ​ ​ ​ Is 2.5-coloring in [rational-unifor](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.397.5306&rep=rep1&type=pdf)m [ACC0](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:A#acc0)?

Is 2.5-coloring with k in n<sup>[o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)(1)</sup> hard for [rational-unifor](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.397.5306&rep=rep1&type=pdf)m [TC0](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:T#tc0)?

Is there a function g in [ω](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)(log) such that 2.5-coloring with k in n<sup>[o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)(1)</sup> is GC(g(n),[AC0](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:A#ac0))-hard?

Is 2.5-coloring with k in n<sup>[o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)(1)</sup> hard for ​ GC ( k$\cdot$O(log(n)) , DSPACE(O(log(n))) ) ?

What about the "infinitely-often" versions of any of those questions,

i.e., for pairs k,n such that k is in n<sup>o(1)</sup> and is arbitrarily large?

Comment: This problem is cool!  Thanks for sharing.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I now realize that one of the questions I gave at the bottom of my OP is trivial,

and for another, a yes answer would have a simple unlikely consequence.

As I stated in my OP, 2.5-coloring is logspace-complete even with k=0,

so it certainly is hard for TC0, and if it's in ACC0 then ​ ACC0 = logspace .)

More interestingly, I [recently learned about](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/33240/6973) the odd cycle transversal problem. ​ By using Reingold's algorithm as I mentioned in my OP, odd cycle transversal is logspace-equivalent to 2.5-coloring. ​ Accordingly, [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.3068) yields a significant amount of information

"about the complexity of 2.5-coloring", and [this paper](http://www.user.tu-berlin.de/hueffner/bipartization-jgaa08.pdf) gives a faster algorithm for it.